# NetBeans Platform: Action disabled, but shortcut active

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, action, toolbar, netbeans-platform

After putting in a month of work on my application, I have discovered something peculiar. I have a Viewer module where all TopComponents are, and a MenuToolbar module which is where I keep all my toolbar actions. Here is my add:

```
package com.demo.toolbar;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import org.openide.awt.ActionRegistration;
import org.openide.awt.ActionReference;
import org.openide.awt.ActionReferences;
import org.openide.awt.ActionID;
import org.openide.util.NbBundle.Messages;

@ActionID(category = "Edit",
id = "com.demo.toolbar.AddAction")
@ActionRegistration(iconBase = "com/demo/toolbar/icons/add.png",
displayName = "#CTL_AddAction")
@ActionReferences({
    @ActionReference(path = "Toolbars/AddEditDelete", position = 1),
    @ActionReference(path = "Shortcuts", name = "D-A")
})
@Messages("CTL_AddAction=Add")
public final class AddAction implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //code here
    }
}
```

That shortcut is activated via CTRL+A and it puts TopComponent into an add mode.  I also have a DeleteAction which is activated with CTRL+D command. When the person hits CTRL+A, the following happens:

```
List<Component> c = new ArrayList<Component>();
        c.addAll(Arrays.asList(ToolbarPool.getDefault().findToolbar("AddEditDelete").getComponents()));
if (mode.equals("add")) {
    for (Component component : c) {
        component.setEnabled(false);
        }
        c.get(13).setEnabled(true);
        c.get(14).setEnabled(true);
}
```

So basically whenever a user hits Add button on the toolbar, it disables all other buttons (including delete) so the users can't perform those actions while in Add mode.

However, they can still hit CTRL+D to delete. Which is a big no-no...

How can I go about fixing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You should not enable/disable actions directly. Take a look at [the Actions API](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-actions/org/openide/actions/doc-files/api.html). `CookieAction` might be what you want. The idea is to publish a Cookie (some context) to the global lookup. Your Cookie aware actions are automatically enabled/disabled depending on the presence of the Cookie.

In fact this is how the save button in the IDE works. Whenever an editor puts a `SaveCookie` to the global context, the toolbar button and Ctrl+S are enabled; as described [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/savecookie)

You might consider using a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) to control the presence of the cookies in a clean way.

Comment: I tried and after about a week, I still haven't been able to come up with even a remotely working prototype. My goal is to have Action1, Action2 and Action3 (all custom actions, created with NB Wizard), where clicking Action1 will disable action1 and action2, and clicking Action3 will enable 1 and 2 but disable 3. If you have a link to a sort of tutorial which shows CookieAction implementation in a more thorough way than the API, I would greatly appreciate it. I do agree that using some sort of globalcontext is better than directly controlling the actions.